# Hiding paper-tabs dynamically in Polymer

Tags: polymer

Need to hide  element depending on user click.
Tried setting hidden$="{{hideme}}" and changed hideme using this.$.xxx.hideme=true
Also as referred in few discussions changed hidden$="{{hideme()}}" to a function returning value. But both did not work.
What is the right way to set the hidden attribute?

Comment: Tried paper-tabs
    {
      display:block;
    } and           this.$.mytabs.style.display = 'none';     While element gets hidden its not getting removed from DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hidden$="{{hideme}}` and `hidden$="{{hideme()}}"` are correct and would both set the `hidden` attribute, assuming the `hideme` property and `hideme()` function are both defined in the host element.

For example, if the `<x-foo>` element contained:

```
<paper-tabs hidden$="{{hideme}}">
```

...then you could hide the `<paper-tabs>` element by setting `<x-foo>.hideme` to `true`.

Note in Polymer 2, you apparently need to define your own `[hidden]` CSS rule in the host element's styles:

```
<dom-module id="x=foo">
  <template>
    <style>
      [hidden] {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
    ...
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/rdVaVY?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks a ton, this works like a charm. While in the codepen example you shared, once tabs are hidden, DOM gets realigned and text content moves up. But in my case that's not happening while the tabs gets hidden. Text content remains there creating a gap. Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: I don't think the hidden property requires a $. I've been using it without.